# Giving different style to mapped object elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
const serviceInfo = [

    {
        name : "Web & Mobile design",
        details :  " We craft stunning and amazing web UI, using a well drafted UX to fit your product.",
        image: service1
    },

    {
        name: "Graphic design",
        details: "Amazing flyers, social media posts and brand representations that would make your brand stand out.",
        image: service2
    },

    {
        name : "Web development",
        details : "With well written codes, we build amazing apps for all platforms, mobile and web apps in general.",
        image: service3
    }
]
```

this is the object I've declared. I'm applying map function on this object and using bootstrap 4 for my app. I want to apply different styles to each of these mapped elements. How can I do that?

Comment: You can add another property `style` in each object and use it inside your `map`. Try it and show us the result

Answer (score 0):

you can add another property like `className` and specify different styles for each object:

```
    const serviceInfo = [

    {
        name : "Web & Mobile design",
        details :  " We craft stunning and amazing web UI, using a well drafted UX to fit your product.",
        image: service1,
        className: "service1"
    },

    {
        name: "Graphic design",
        details: "Amazing flyers, social media posts and brand representations that would make your brand stand out.",
        image: service2,
        className: "service2"
    },

    {
        name : "Web development",
        details : "With well written codes, we build amazing apps for all platforms, mobile and web apps in general.",
        image: service3,
        className: "service3"
    }
    ]
```

then in your css:

```
    .service1 {
      // styles...
    }
    .service2 {
      // styles...
    }
    .service3 {
      // styles...
    }
```

and map it

```
return(
    {serviceInfo.map(
        info=>(
          <div className={info.className}>...</div>
              );
       )
     }
```